# How does one construct a rigorous proof?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, discrete-mathematics

I know this may sound too vague to be given a thought but I realised that this is a problem I often have when I have to prove a given statement. How does one actually go about setting parameters that will constitute a (generally) rigorous proof? Especially in real analysis, where a proof has to be cogent. I like proofs but,I sometimes find myself writing things that I think are relevant to the proof,only to find out that there is no order in the proof steps. I would really appreciate your help on this. (examples illustrating the thought process in a proof would also be greatly appreciated)

Comment: For real analysis, [this](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/how-to-work-out-proofs-in-analysis-i/), and some of the other posts on Timothy Gowers's blog in the category "IA Analysis" may be of interest to you.

Comment: All implications should be sound and there should be no holes. The level of detail might be dependent on the level of the reader you want to convince.

Comment: I must say, I'm mostly prone to having those holes in my proofs because of the temptation of thinking of some steps as being ''too obvious'' to be proved - a rather most dangerous statement in all of mathematics! I desire to overcome this weakness!

Answer (score 0):

A demonstration to be such, really a proof, must lack any error. That said, there may be a rigorous proof both short and long, depending, in general, of the character and knowledge of who makes it. Often a proof is described as poor by those who read it: they consider that some of the (true) steps of the proof deserve to be explained while who makes it considers these steps as well known.Indeed, almost all proof if you are required to be at all keen on detail, it would be too long (because of the nature of the facts).Sorry for bad English.